# Is the C++ core guideline C35 "A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual" wrong for interface classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, virtual-functions, cpp-core-guidelines

Say I have the following interface class in order to "Write to interfaces, not implementations":

```
class IDrawable
{
public:

    virtual void
    Draw() const = 0;

protected:

    ~IDrawable() = default;
};
```

Clients should not be able to delete dynamically allocated drawables trough a interface pointer so `IDrawable`'s destructor is made protected and non-virtual, as per [C++ Core guideline C.35: A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-nonvirtual)

Now for a class that implements this interface:

```
class CDrawable : public IDrawable
{
public:

    void
    Draw() const override;
};
```

This, off course, emits a warning:

> `CDrawable` has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor.

To solve this we now have to add a virtual destructor to `CDrawable`. But it feels like a code smell to have a virtual destructor in a derived class, I've not seen that before (?) Wouldn't it make more sense to have a virtual protected destructor in `IDrawable`, contrary to what the guideline says?

Comment: The problem here is not in C.35 itself. It is that the compiler and the IsoCppCoreGuidelines have a different opinion. If you want to, you can try making `CDrawable` `final` and check if the compiler still emits a warning.

Answer (score 2):

There is technically no issue. Your `CDrawable` has a public non-virtual destructor (implicitly defined). Invoking it doesn't cause undefined behaviour, unless of course it is invoked on a class derived from `CDrawable`. If you only have a reference to a `IDrawable` and invoked its destructor, you would skip destruction of the derived class (causing UB, I think), but since it's not publicly accessible, that is not a problem.

Yes, you get a warning. However, that warning is just that, an indication that something may be at fault. In this case, it isn't.

Comment: Most warnings from a compiler can be suppressed (or are suppressed by default).  In this case, there may be justification to suppress this particular warning.